# Where and how to place Ajax call for Bootstrap modal content

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, bootstrap-modal

This is a simple nodejs test app (project download link is added below) using express, pug template engine and jquery. It serves an HTML form with input for two numbers and adds them together on the server-side at the click of a button (the calculation is to be replaced with a complex calculation and database query) and **shows the result in a modal dialog that pops up when the user clicks the submit button.**

Very basic at this point:

[image: screenshot of the test app]

The "Add numbers classic" button sends a classic POST to the server and reloads page with added result. 
The "Add numbers modal" opens the modal but not more at the moment.

I am stuck with

- Where to put functions so that clicking the button opens the modal
  AND makes a server request.
- Which function to add and with what arguments
- How to deal with the request in my server side app.js. is it a normal POST route? how to structure the result and send it back so it will be displayed in the modal?

I tried to find an answer online for two days. I am grateful for any hint that can point me in the right direction!

[You can download the project folder, just "npm install" to install npm packages](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDf03cNOdQijaaxjnbAL8CuKLNdsSNhx/view?usp=sharing)

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var fetchRouter = require('./routes/fetch');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/fetch', fetchRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.js (router)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var sum = 0;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'This is the website', resultnumber: sum  });
});

//my stuff
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  sum = parseFloat(req.body.nb1) + parseFloat(req.body.nb2)
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    res.render('index', { title: 'This is the website', resultnumber: sum  });
  }, 1500);

});

module.exports = router;
```

index.pug (template)

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to the Website

  form(method='POST' action='/')
    div.form-group
        label(for='nb1') Number 1:
        input#nb1.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Number 1' name='nb1')
    div.form-group
        label(for='nb2') Number 2:
        input#nb2.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Number 2' name='nb2')
    //button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Add these together
    button(type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-lg') Add numbers classic

  button(type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal') Add numbers modal

  if(resultnumber != 0)
    p Sum:
    p #{resultnumber}

  // Modal
  #myModal.modal.fade(role='dialog')
    .modal-dialog
      // Modal content
      .modal-content
        .modal-header
          button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') ×
          h4.modal-title Modal Result
        .modal-body
          p The result is supposed to be shown here. 
          script(type="text/javascript").
            var counter = 0
            console.log('das skript',counter++)
        .modal-footer
          button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close
```

Comment: Fix the file link.

Comment: link fixed! thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

(As you are using jQuery)
After clicking the button make ajax call to the calculation endpoint. After receiving the response from endpoint (your desired result) populate the modal (using jquery/js) and then show the modal.

Sample code:
**SERVER**

```
//my stuff
router.post('/calculation', function(req, res, next) {
  sum = parseFloat(req.body.nb1) + parseFloat(req.body.nb2);
  res.status(200).json({ data : sum });
});
```

**CLIENT**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/calculation",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    nb1: num1,
    nb2: num2
  },
  success: function(json) {
    if(json.status == 200){
      // Show your modal. For example:
      $('.modal-body p').text(json.data); // Setting result to modal
      $('#myModal').modal('show'); // Showing modal
    }else {
      // Show error message
      $('#login-error').text("Invalid login.");
    }
  },

  error: function() {
    // Probably something wrong with the server.
    $('#login-error').text("Server error.");
  }   
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you! I get your code. This is exactly what I was looking for. But where exactly in my (assuming) index.pug do I need to place the client part so it gets called in the right moment? I'm very new to this.

Comment: I've never used pug. I like ejs. Lets assume you have a main.js for your client side coding where you will put all your jQuery and other client side stuff. Include the main.js into the index.pug (using <script> tag) just before closing the body tag (don't know how to do it in pug). Place the CLIENT code inside the main.js file. Now, add button click action in the js file. When button click happens run the ajax call I've mentioned above and do you want with the data.